# How to make nested DIV exact same width as parent div

Tags: css

I have a div nested inside another. The parent div contains the title for a drop down menu. The inner div contains the choices. I have them in different divs so that I can add a scroll to the inner div without it causing the title to scroll. I have borders around both. The inner div looks to be 1px narrower on each of the sides. How do I make the child div exactly the same width as the parent div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your code like?

Try this, it should work:

```
width: 100%;
```

Comment: that works but I run into another issue. I will create a new issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That's what `width:inherit;` is for.

Comment: when I use that, it makes the div only as wide as the text in it. The parent div is position relative, not sure if that matters.